# how to impliment payment-gateway with iphone application?

Tags: iphone

I m developing a iphone where i need to take credit card details from customer and complete the payment cycle.

Now how should i put all this things in my iphone application from scrap. What code and securities a need to put are not known to me at all. So Please help me in this regards.
how to impairment payment-gateway with iphone application ?

All the suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: I think Apple approves only those apps on the Appstore which have In-App purchase, payment mechanism. Apps with other payment gateways may be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple will mostly reject the App which uses payment mechanism internally.

These are the methods which i will suggest

- Paypal iPhone API

Try these [link1](https://www.x.com/people/PP_Mobile_Kent/blog/2010/02/02/paypals-iphone-library-is-getting-ready-for-beta)  [link2](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep) But some paypal feature will get rejected by Apple. So know your feature and make sure that your paypal functionality satisfies the guidelines

- Apple's InApp Purchase.

This is safer since Apple takes care of Transactions
Only problem is Apple takes some % of money for themselves.

Refer : http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

Apple Docs :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

1. ask server guys to create web for payment transfer. and launch that link with in app whenever user want for payment transfer.