# In app purchase for money transaction using iphone sdk

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios5

I am very new to in App Purchase, In my application I need to implement a way for the user to pay some money to the client. Could you guys please give me some ideas on different possibilities.

Do the client and user must need an apple id for transaction?

Comment: If you are trying to have users pay different clients, I think PayPal or some other similar money transfer service would be more suitable than In-App Purchase. I don't think its possible to have In-App Purchases be sent to multiple recipients, at all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your client (as in the person who commissioned this app) and the user both need an apple id. The user needs it to use the app store and in app purchase. The client needs it to become a publisher on the app store and receive payment.

However, you can't just pick and choose if you want to use in app purchase. There are several rules that forbids you to use it for some purposes, as well ar requiring you to use it for others.

As a rule of thumb, if the payment is for functionality or data (such as more levels in a game), or a service (such as cloud data storage) - and you can deliver this immediately, you **must** use in app purchase. In some cases (such as books) you are allowed to accept payment outside of the app, but you are not allowed to link to that payment information from within the app.

If the payment is for a service or gods outside of the app (like a pizza, a donation or a bus ticket), you are **not allowed** to use in app purchase.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use iphone Paypal API for this.

Implementation details may be found in this link: 
[how to impliment payment-gateway with iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689019/how-to-impliment-payment-gateway-with-iphone-application)